# CutyCapt issue with SSL URL

Tags: ssl, qpainter, cutycapt

I am having a problem getting CutyCapt to work with SSL URLs, I have the most recent version of CutyCapt (`CutyCapt.cpp 10 2013-07-14 21:57:37Z`), it works perfect with all non-SSL URLs, when I try to grab a URL with SSL using the following command:

```
./xvfb-run ./CutyCapt --min-width=1280 --min-height=720 --max-wait=6000 \
     --url="https://apple.com" --out="testssl.jpg"
```

I get the following error:

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3

QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints

QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active

QPainter::pen: Painter not active

QPainter::setPen: Painter not active

QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted

./xvfb-run: line 171: kill: (6557) - No such process
```

---

Note: when I run it with no HTTPS, it runs fine:

```
 ./xvfb-run ./CutyCapt --min-width=1280 --min-height=720 --max-wait=6000 \
     --url="http://apple.com" --out="testssl.jpg"
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: hmm. just tried a different url with https, and it worked, why would it grab some https urls and not others?

Comment: Were you able to find a resolution for this?

Comment: What operating system are you on and which version of QT are you running? I've been unable to reproduce those errors with the same commands. It seems from looking around the issue it may be related to the implementation of Webkit.

Comment: have you tried directly running xvfb without cutycapt for https?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stumbling upon this like me.

Install Qt5 (you're going to need it). You're going to run into several package issues, just google each error and you'll fix them(you'll be back on StackOverflow several times).

After that, install the latest CutyCapt, and run it with the --insecure parameter. This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04.