# CutyCapt pages not loading from https sites

Tags: ssl, https, qpainter, xvfb, cutycapt

I'm using CutyCapt (http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) on CentOS 7 to take a screenshot of my website.  I'm trying to screen capture this site: xmountwashington.appspot.com/csc.html and it works pretty well with this command:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 2048x2048x24" ./CutyCapt --delay=5000 --auto-load-images=on --min-width=1680 --min-height=500 --url=http://xmountwashington.appspot.com --out=example.jpeg
```

I found that the images in the upper-left and upper-right corners were not loading and investigated further.  They're both hotlinked from external https sites.  I found that CutyCapt sometimes has issues with https certificates, so I tried to load one of these pages by themselves:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 2048x2048x24" ./CutyCapt --delay=5000 --auto-load-images=on --min-width=1680 --min-height=500 --url=https://www.mountwashington.org/library/images/common/logo.png --out=example.jpeg
```

but this just hung for a while then eventually returned "painter not active".  Even when using the "--insecure option" (ignoring ssl certificate errors), things still aren't working.  Any ideas?  Seems like a similar problem to this post: [CutyCapt issue with SSL URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890019/cutycapt-issue-with-ssl-urls).   Would more modern webpages not work with CutyCapt?

Comment: were you able to find a resolution?

Comment: That seems to work fine on my system even without the `--insecure` option. Which version of CutyCapt are you using?